# Adding components dynamically to a form not in a limited size C#

Tags: c#, forms

I am dynamically adding labels and textboxes in a form while the program is running. How can I insert these components in a scroll pane so that no matter how many labels and textboxes I add they will fit in the form?

I don't know if I'm being clear.. but what I want is to be able to add as many components as I like and not in the limited size of the form.. is there any way to do this?

This is my code right now:

```
public void generateFormDynamically()
{
      textBoxes = new TextBox[noOfPlayers];

      int xLabel = 95;
      int yLabel = 215;

      int xTextBox = 205;
      int yTextBox = 215;

      for (int i = 0; i < noOfPlayers; i++)
      {
           Label label = new Label();
           label.Text = "Player " + (i + 1) + ":";

           if (i == 0) label.Location = new Point(xLabel, yLabel);
           else
           {
               yLabel += 55;
               label.Location = new Point(xLabel, yLabel);
           }

           label.AutoSize = true;
           label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
           label.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
           label.Name = "label" + (i + 2);
           label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(68, 20);
           label.TabIndex = 6;
           label.Visible = true;
           label.Show();
           this.Controls.Add(label);

           TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

           if (i == 0) textBox.Location = new Point(xTextBox, yTextBox);
           else
           {
                yTextBox += 55;
                textBox.Location = new Point(xTextBox, yTextBox);
           }

           textBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
           textBox.Name = "textBox" + (i + 1);
           textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(245, 20);
           textBox.TabIndex = 1;
           textBox.Text = "Player" + (i + 1);
           textBox.Visible = true;
           textBox.Show();
           textBoxes[i] = textBox;
           this.Controls.Add(textBox);
     }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How do you put forty pounds of flour in a twenty pound bag?  You use a scrollable bag.  Set the form's AutoScroll property to true or use a FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: I set AutoScroll property to true but the labels are still overlapping other components

Comment: You'll need to give them a proper Location property value if they overlap stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, you can not add it to fixed form, and then adjust form. eventually, form will be too big. BUT, you can do is:

1) add a panel on the form, the panel size is fixed (or anchored/docked).
2) set panel AutoScroll to true.
3) then add label/textbox.

so, if too many label/textbox added, the scrollbar will show up.

but still, it is a good idea to set a limit for the # of dynamic control.

Comment: yes that's more reasonable thanks :) worked just fine! and yes I have a limit for the no. of components to add :) Thanks for your answer!